# Memory leak using multidimensional Array

Tags: iphone

[image]
i got memoery leak at that multidimensional mutable array i need to remove those leak because due to this leak app is not working in iphone,i dnt how remove this leak

> CGRect                bounds =[self bounds];

```
UITouch*            touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
if (firstTouch) {
    firstTouch = NO;
    previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;
    NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [undo addObject:temp];
    /***** add 1st point *********/
    [[undo objectAtIndex:[undo count] -1] addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousLocation]];

    if(mcount==1)
    {
        [masking addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
        [[masking objectAtIndex:[masking count]-1] addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousLocation]];
    }
} else {

    location = [touch locationInView:self];
    location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
    previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;


    [[undo objectAtIndex:[undo count] -1]addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousLocation]];

    if(mcount==1)
    {
         [[masking objectAtIndex:[masking count]-1] addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousLocation]];
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question asked here.  What is your question?  What have you tried?  Have you narrowed it down at all?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

appears to be leaking. Release `temp` when you're finished with it or `autorelease` it in this line.

This line:

```
[masking addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
```

is also problematic. Since there is no direct pointer, I recomment `autorelease` (or rewriting this code, but I digress).

Also possibly helpful for you is that you can change

```
[undo objectAtIndex:[undo count] -1]
```

to instead be

```
[undo lastObjectAtIndex]
```

Comment: the line with `addObject:` can be changed to an autoreleased array with factory method like `[masking addObject:[NSMutableArray array]]`

Comment: you shouldn't use autorelease objects in loops. Use -[newArray mutableCopy]; instead - create NSMutableArray before entering the loop, then before using array -[removeAllObjects]; from it, then add any objects (or leave as it is) and add to the parent collection via -[masking addObject:[temp mutableCopy]];